# Script to test wordlist against Truectypt volume?

Tags: truecrypt

I forget the password for one of my truecrypt volumes. I remember part of the password and have an idea what other parts could be. I want to crate worldlist of all password variations that come to my mind and use a script to test this wordlist against the truectypt volume.

I found this CMD script but it is not very convenient because you have to enter the words in a row:

`FOR %%A IN (password1 password2 password3) DO "C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe" /a /s /l x /q /v folder.tc /p %%A`

How to make the script to use a text file which contains the words and each word in the list is on a new line?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `FOR` line is otherwise correct, what you want is:

> `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (passwords.txt) DO "C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe" /a /s /l x /q /v folder.tc /p %%A`

Based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163873/367865).

Comment: Thanks, the script is working. One more question: is possible to make the script use combination of words that are in the list? Like if the list contains the words red, blue, black to try all possible combinations with the words in different order: redblue, blueblack, blackredblue... Or this becomes to complicated to be done with a simple script?

Comment: @peter7558 Doing that goes a bit beyond what batch scripts are capable of. Perhaps a more versatile language.